# Suggestions for Managing PostgreSQL Users and Permissions

Tags: postgresql, devops

Is there a recommended application/tool for efficiently managing PostgreSQL users/roles? 
We have a considerable number of users and require an application that allows us to view and manage permissions for users across databases, tables, and schemas. 
Additionally, we need the ability to add users through the application. 
Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.